# How to remove 'add to cart' button from one cms page only?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have created a web store with custom CMS page which has custom layout too. This page will show all the products of the store.

On that CMS page **all the product is displaying** but

**I want to remove 'add to cart' button, 'add to wishlist' link and 'add to compare' link from products**

I want to remove these links from that specific CMS page only.

I tried

```
<remove name="" />
```

in Layout Update XML of that CMS page but I can't get specific names to remove and while searching I tried every possible name but no success.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have used a custom layout and you are displaying all products on that page then you  must have used block type to display all products in content of that page.

Something like

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list_random" name="product" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Simply make a new file and save it on same loction where list.phtml is saved (obviously with different name say new.phtml

Put that new.phtml instead of list.phtml

And delete whatever you don't want to display on that page from new.phtml

Comment: It works. Thanks. Let see what comes next. I have lots of magento doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You only can remove whole **blocks** with layout updates like that, but those links and buttons are not separate blocks but get rendered within the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` block. You will have to replace the template of this block with your own:

1. copy `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` to `/app/design/frontend/YOUR/THEME/template/WHATEVER/catalog/product/list.phtml` (use your theme directory and a directory name under template that refers to your CMS page)
2. edit this copy and remove the links and buttons
3. in the layout update handle for your CMS page, add:

**XML:**

```
<reference name="product_list">
    <action method="setTemplate" template="WHATEVER/catalog/product/list.phtml" />
</reference>
```

(assuming that the product list block is called `product_list`)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this first but nothing changes. My theme list.phtml is stored in app\design\frontend\default\mytheme\template\catalog\product. Can't get what to write in XML in place of WHATEVER. Tried every path :(

Comment: WHATEVER = whatever you like. It should just be the same both times.

Comment: Tried that path with no success. BTW in reference tag I put content.

Comment: Should have been "product" as I can see from the other answer. But I also see that you specified the template right there, so the layout XML is not necessary at all.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Certainly will try this too.

Answer (score 0):

Then, depending on what you want to remove, you can put between the "default" tags the following lines:

```
<remove name="cart_sidebar" />  "  

<remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />  "
```

http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/remove-default-blocks/manual-removal